# Squid3 not caching larger files

Tags: squid

I try to use squid to cache rpm packages fetched from a yum repository. With the following configuration, it works well for a small rpms, but it would not cache larger ones like openjdk.

From the log file (below), it seems that it does not cache files larger than 4MB even though the `maximum_object_size 128 MB` is set.

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

squid.conf:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
http_port 3128 transparent
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 4048 16 256
maximum_object_size 128 MB
refresh_pattern Packages\.bz2$ 0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Sources\.bz2$  0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Release\.gpg$  0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Release$       0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern -i .(deb|rpm|exe|zip|tar|tgz|bz2|ram|rar|bin)$  129600 100% 129600 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store
refresh_pattern .              0       20%     4320
```

Following is a log when trying to install openjdk:

```
1400481405.110    408 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 852 GET http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? - HIER_DIRECT/72.232.223.58 text/plain
1400481405.325    162 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 4202 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml - HIER_DIRECT/81.194.43.155 text/xml
1400481408.357   3018 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 4614150 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/repodata/617a880b84a87969e04bfeebb1b96d5f441da42ee931d374fa6b6d57decd821e-primary.sqlite.bz2 - HIER_DIRECT/81.194.43.155 application/x-bzip2
1400481409.332    182 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 904 GET http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? - HIER_DIRECT/72.232.223.58 text/plain
1400481409.446     41 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 3814 GET http://centos.crazyfrogs.org/6.5/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml - HIER_NONE/- text/xml
1400481409.451      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 19492 GET http://centos.crazyfrogs.org/6.5/extras/x86_64/repodata/966094530f6744d0b6a3fc45b10cbd845577945fbd6a43448defbe1fab902c38-primary.sqlite.bz2 - HIER_NONE/- application/x-bzip2
1400481409.638    183 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 920 GET http://mirrorlist.centos.org/? - HIER_DIRECT/72.232.223.58 text/plain
1400481409.743     53 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 3856 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml - HIER_NONE/- application/xml
1400481409.775     30 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 3273269 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/repodata/395b793d10b8ac3be091e715aeeb7af5f64a699c18d14e0a19c5bc67db6425ee-primary.sqlite.bz2 - HIER_NONE/- application/x-bzip2
1400481410.703      3 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 379438 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/alsa-lib-1.0.22-3.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481410.712      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 249014 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/flac-1.2.1-6.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481410.717      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 190514 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/fontconfig-2.8.0-3.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481410.724      5 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 368066 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/freetype-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481410.728      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 37880 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/giflib-4.1.6-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481424.776  14044 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 27050980 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el6_5.x86_64.rpm - HIER_DIRECT/91.121.124.139 application/x-redhat-package-manager
1400481430.595   5698 172.17.0.3 TCP_MISS/200 9850394 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el6_5.x86_64.rpm - HIER_DIRECT/91.121.124.139 application/x-redhat-package-manager
1400481430.646      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 61088 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/jpackage-utils-1.7.5-3.12.el6.noarch.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.650      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 54448 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libICE-1.0.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.652      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 37948 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libSM-1.2.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.661      7 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 598770 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libX11-1.5.0-4.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.667      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 196782 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libX11-common-1.5.0-4.el6.noarch.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.671      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 25300 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libXau-1.0.6-4.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.674      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 35888 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libXext-1.3.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.676      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 139605 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/libXfont-1.4.5-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/x-redhat-package-manager
1400481430.680      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 36028 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libXi-1.6.1-3.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.681      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 31400 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libXrender-0.9.7-2.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.685      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 30284 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libXtst-1.2.1-2.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.688      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 25320 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libasyncns-0.8-1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.691      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 25396 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libfontenc-1.0.5-2.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.694      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 178925 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/x-redhat-package-manager
1400481430.698      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 21776 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libogg-1.1.4-2.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.703      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 186422 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libpng-1.2.49-1.el6_2.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.710      5 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 238658 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libsndfile-1.0.20-5.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.714      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 172210 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libvorbis-1.2.3-4.el6_2.1.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.717      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 112834 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/libxcb-1.8.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.722      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 72289 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.730      6 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 473122 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/pulseaudio-libs-0.9.21-14.el6_3.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.734      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 63868 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-57.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.738      1 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 44284 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/ttmkfdir-3.0.9-32.1.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.742      0 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 151141 GET http://mirror.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/tzdata-java-2014b-1.el6.noarch.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/x-redhat-package-manager
1400481430.749      2 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 77097 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
1400481430.763      6 172.17.0.3 TCP_HIT/200 532402 GET http://miroir.univ-paris13.fr/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.2-9.1.el6.noarch.rpm - HIER_NONE/- application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was solved by Plamen at the [squid-user](http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-caching-larger-files-td4666004.html#a4666006) mailing list. The `maximum_object_size 128 MB` should be above the `cache_dir` in the `squid.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks for the information! That is crazy, given that the ordering you had (and which I had too) comes from the default squid3.conf... I wonder if the squid developers are going to fix this (either the ordering in the default config file, or making this work in any order)...